# Nginx SSL-rewrite to localhost

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, rewrite, url

I want to redirect localhost request to HTTPS. This is what my .conf looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localhost.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localhost.key;

  server_name localhost;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

I run this in a Docker container with `-p 80:80 -p 443:443` but calling the server from the browser results in a loop of `https://localhost/` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your `https` and `http` servers share the same configuration block, which tells nginx to redirect to `https://$server_name$request_uri` address. That is the reason for the redirect loop.

You need to have a separate `server` block for `https`, where you serve the actual content, and you only have the redirect in the `http` block.

In your case the configuration would look something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localhost.key;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```